# Bigger playing card value in a different class (JAVA)

Tags: java, playing-cards

I'm trying to compare two cards object and get the biggest one.
The Program is made of 2 classes, but I can't figure how to get the biggest value between 2 cards.

Class 1 contains this piece of code:

```
Pelikortti kortti1 = new Pelikortti("risti",7);
Pelikortti kortti2 = new Pelikortti("ruutu",8);
System.out.println(suurempi(kortti1,kortti2)); //expected: ruutu 8
```

This line is supposed to print `ruutu 8` as it is the card with the biggest value. "suurempi" means "bigger" in my language.

Class 2 looks like this so far:

```
public class Pelikortti {

    private String maa1;
    private int arvo1;


    public Pelikortti(String maa, int arvo){
        if(parametritOK(maa,arvo)){
            this.maa1 = maa;
            this.arvo1 = arvo;
        }else{
            this.maa1 = "?";
            this.arvo1 = -1;
        }
    }

    public Pelikortti() {
        this.maa1 = "?";
        this.arvo1 = -1;
    }

    private static boolean parametritOK(String maa, int arvo){
        return (maa.equals("risti")||maa.equals("ruutu")||
                maa.equals("pata")||maa.equals("hertta")) 
                && arvo > 1 && arvo < 15;
    }

    public void setKortti(String maa, int arvo){
        if(parametritOK(maa,arvo)){
            this.maa1 = maa;
            this.arvo1 = arvo;
        }else{
            this.maa1 = "?";
            this.arvo1 = -1;
        }
    }

    public String getMaa() {
        return maa1;
    }

    public int getArvo() {
        return arvo1;
    }

    public int suurempi(Pelikortti kortti1, Pelikortti kortti2){
        if(kortti1>kortti2){
            return kortti1;
        }
        return kortti2;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return(this.maa1 + " " + this.arvo1);
    }
}
```

The second class has a lot of other methods too as it is a part of another assignment, but the problem here is that I can't get the comparing method to work when called from Class 1.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to compare is the card value. And the value is not the card object itself but the attribute containing the value: `arvo1`.

So you need to compare the correct attribute of each object: `kortti1.arvo1` and `kortti2.arvo2`.

Note that this attribute is private, you won't access it directly from another instance, so you will need to use the getter `getArvo()`.

Also, `suurempi` is not a static method, it needs to be called from a class instance. So it will need only one parameter (`kortti2`) as `kortti1` will be the instance the method is called from.

You also need to change the method returned type to `Pelikortti`as you want to get the card object and not just it's value (Thanks eltabo for the edit)

```
public Pelikortti suurempi(Pelikortti kortti2){
    if(this.arvo1>kortti2.getArvo()){
        return this;
    }
    return kortti2;
}
```

The method call:

```
System.out.println(kortti1.suurempi(kortti2));
```

**EDIT:**

If the call to `suurempi` has to be from another class (let's call it `ClassA`) and follow this syntax:

```
System.out.println(suurempi(kortti1,kortti2));
```

That means `suurempi` is defined in `ClassA` and not in `Pelikortti` and you need to move your code.

Then it's very similar excepted you don't use `this` but the correct parameter.

```
public Pelikortti suurempi(Pelikortti kortti1, Pelikortti kortti2){
    if(kortti1.getArvo()>kortti2.getArvo()){
        return kortti1;
    }
    return kortti2;
}
```

Comment: I was given the method call 
        System.out.println(suurempi(kortti1,kortti2)); 
for this so is there a way I could stick to it?

Comment: Depending where you call this method, yes.

Comment: The call method is supposed to be in the same package but in a different java class. That's the problem I couldn't solve

Comment: If you have to keep the syntax `suurempi(kortti1,kortti2)` and call this from another class, you should probably move the `suurempi(..)` method to the class calling it. Then, from my code, you just need to add the parameter `Pelikortti kortti1`, change `this.arvo1` to `kortti1.getArvo()` and `return this;`to `return kortti1;` I will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are comparing cards, instead of cards values

```
public static Pelikortti suurempi(Pelikortti kortti1, Pelikortti kortti2){
    if(kortti1.getArvo()>kortti2.getArvo()){
        return kortti1;
    }
    return kortti2;
}
```

you can then use the function like this:

```
System.out.println(Pelikortti.suurempi(kortti1,kortti2));
```

Comment: How can I make it to compare the values of cards? by using that calling method on class 1

Comment: @user9629396 what do you mean by "using that calling method on class 1"? do you want to use "suurempi" as a function, without being related to class 2?

Comment: I'm supposed to use System.out.println(suurempi(kortti1,kortti2)) as the method to use the other class in finding the card that has a bigger value

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't directly compare objects as you would integers, and that's why you're getting a compilation error in `int suurempi(Pelikortti kortti1, Pelikortti kortti2)`

Your goal is to have `System.out.println(suurempi(kortti1,kortti2));` to print out `ruutu 8` from Class 1.

First, the method `int suurempi(Pelikortti kortti1, Pelikortti kortti2)` is defined on `Pelikortti` and the call is made from Class 1 without using a `Pelikortti` object, so the method won't be used. Also, it returns an integer and not the bigger `Pelikortti`.

Then, to keep things simple, let's make this `suurempi` method return a `Pelikortti` object, so that `System.out.println` prints out the biggest card by getting the card object `String` representation via its `toString()` instance method, overriden from `java.lang.Object`.

### Solution

We need to define the method as follows in Class 1:

```
public Pelikortti suurempi(Pelikortti kortti1, Pelikortti kortti2) {
   return kortti1.getArvo() >= kortti2.getArvo() ? kortti1 : kortti2;
}
```

This assumes you're calling `suurempi` from an instance method of Class 1, if you're calling it from a static method like `public void main(String[] args)`, then you need to make `suurempi` static too.

### More on the topic

The comparison implementation suggested above returns the first `Pelikortti` if the cards have the same value (which is how `Math.max()` works for example), but you can look into the interfaces `java.lang.Comparable` and `java.util.Comparator` for standard ways of comparing objects in Java, which allow to have an equal outcome, in case the two cards have the same value.